# How to collect several files in same directory using Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have several xml files I want to collect to one big xml file.
  How to do this using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mergexml) package for merging xml files. It has various options and configurations.